# Does a "force" work in comics?

Tags: comics, smoke-and-mirrors

In issue #1 of *Smoke and Mirrors*, the magician asks Ethan to pick a card (the reader is shown the five cards from Ethan's point of view):

> Well here. If you're so certain I'm switching the cards, let's try it again. Look at these. Now think of one. Go ahead.
> Got one?

[image: Cards being held by the magician, showing in order from left to right from the viewer's perspective: nine of diamonds, seven of spades, ace of hearts, four of hearts and the king of diamonds.]

and then reveals 'knowledge' of which card was picked:

> This was the one you picked.

The point is that he is using trickery (a "force") rather than real magic, which is common in Ethan's world.

The cards are on page 23; the reveal of which card was picked is on page 24.  I picked the same card as Ethan.

[image: The same cards but with the four of hearts is being picked by the magician.]

Is this a coincidence? (There is a 20% chance of a random match, of course).  Or is the technique behind a "force" applicable even when the magician isn't physically present?

If there is an example of using this trick in other earlier comics about magic, that would be a great data point to include in an answer.

Comment: Tony - (1) what are the cards for those of use who don't have the comic? (2) Are you OK with out of universe answer?

Comment: (2) Also, what are the details of the trick? E.g. did the magician say something to him when describing the trick? (e.g. "pick any card, say 20")?

Comment: @DVK added images.  Out-of-universe is fine.

Comment: also, why does the heart on the center of the ace flip upside down?

Comment: @zephyr that just means the whole card is upside down.  No reason that some wouldn't be.

Comment: @TonyMeyer ok, but look at the top panel - maybe I'm misreading it, but it doesn't seem like there's much opportunity for it to get flipped around between them.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I recall (no references, sorry), when people pick cards/numbers at random, they avoid any extremes. That means the person is unlikely to pick physically edge cards (diamonds) or value-edge ones (Ace/two).

This leaves only 2 cards and one of them is the ONLY black. Also less likely.

**4 of hearts is the only one left that isn't a subconscious outlier.**

An extra benefit is that it's one of 2 heart cards, again people are more subconsciously likely to pick a card that has more of the same suit.

So, your chances are a lot higher than 20%, if you take into account that humans do NOT pick at random.

Plus, there are other ways to prep the mark - e.g. you use one of the cards in the set as an example shown to the mark earlier - they will again subconsciously avoid that card.

Comment: In addition to my successful career as StackExchange user, I can also send you your inheritance of $2 million from my office in Nigeria where I work as a barrister.